# Show that $\mu((-\infty,x])$ is a unique measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to solve this homework problem.

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$ where

$\mu((-\infty,x])= \begin{cases} \frac{5x}{x+1} \text{ for } x>0 \\ 0 \text{ for } x\leq 0 \end{cases}$

The measure is finite. We see that $\mu((-\infty,x]) \leq \frac{5x}{x+1}=\frac{5}{1+1/x} \leq 5$ for all x>0

My textbook theorem says that if that the paving $\mathbb{D}$ is stable under intersections then two measure $\mu$ and $\gamma$ are equal. I am guessing that $\mathbb{D}=(-\infty,x]$ in this case but not sure

For any $x > y > 0$ we have that $\mu((-\infty,x]) \bigcap \mu((-\infty,y])=\mu((-\infty,y]) \in \mathbb{D}$ so it is stable under intersections.

We also see that $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{D}$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$

My conclusion is that the measure is unique. But is this correct? Is this the way to show it or prove it?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is a paving defined as?

Comment: This is all the information - it is an exam problem from 2015

Comment: You said your textbook defined a paving $\mathbb{D}$. I can provide an answer but if you would prefer it using a paving I need to know what that is.

Comment: @Duncan The theorem talks about a paving, that's why I mentioned it. I think you can just disregard it

Comment: I don't know what paving is, but you might argue as follows: suppose $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two measures that agree on all intervals $(a, b]$. Now the collection of sets on which  $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$  agree is a $\sigma$-algebra so in fact they must agree on all of the Borel sets.

Comment: @Matematleta They only agree on $(-\infty,x]$

Comment: @Matematleta Are you sure about that? Don't you mean $(-\infty,x]^c$?

Comment: Ugh typo. Indeed, $x<y\Rightarrow (-\infty,x]^c\cap (-\infty,y]=(x,y]$

Comment: @Matematleta You are assuming closed under complement. This is not assumed in the question

Comment: $\sigma-$ algebras are closed under complement. And $\mu $ is a measure defined on the Borel $\sigma-$algebra or am I misreading your question?

Comment: In any case, define $F(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{5x}{x+1} \text{ for } x>0 \\ 0 \text{ for } x\leq 0 \end{cases}$. Then $F$ is right-continuous, non-decreasing so it induces a unique measure on the Borel sets, which you can check agrees with yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be a measure such that $\lambda((-\infty, x]) = \mu((-\infty, x])$, but $\lambda \neq \mu$. Define $E \subseteq (-\infty, x])$ as $E = (\infty, x']$, where $x \geq x' \geq 0$. As $\lambda((-\infty, x]) - \mu((-\infty, x])) = 0$ and $\lambda \neq \mu, \lambda((-\infty, x])\setminus E ) - \mu((-\infty, x])\setminus E) \neq 0$. But $\lambda((-\infty, x])\setminus E ) - \mu((-\infty, x]\setminus E ) = \lambda((x', x]) - \lambda((-\infty, x']) -\mu((x', x]) + \mu((-\infty, x']) = \lambda(x', x]) - \mu((x', x])] = 0 \implies \lambda(x', x]) = \mu((x', x])$.