# Is $\mu$ a unique probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

**Problem**

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})),$ which fulfills

$$  \mu([x,\infty)) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x+1},  & x>0 \\
1, & x\leq0
\end{cases}$$

Is $\mu$ a unique probability measure on  $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))?$

I don't really have a qualified attempt, because i can't find any theory in our book, and there really isn't anything when i search for a similar example.

Also, what does $[x,\infty)$ in the argument for $\mu([x,\infty))$ mean?

Can anybody lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Please take a look at our guidelines for how to [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Your last question makes me think that perhaps you should start by writing down and examining the definition of a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, and trying to apply that definition to figure out what $\mu([x,\infty))$ could mean. If you can formulate a mathematical question describing your troubles, that would make a much better post.

Comment: You may also find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties) useful, since the CDF $x\mapsto P(X\le x)$ is closely related to your $P(X\ge x).$

Comment: wait no need to accept my answer yet. i'm not so sure. or are you sure? eg if you know the value at $\pi(\mathbb R)$ then it's unique (given it's a probability measure)?

Comment: @BCLC your answer is more than enough, it both gave a great understanding and definitely something to work with.

Comment: @Flems ok but i want you to tell me if no one else does why you think it's unique because i can't seem to articulate it well enough.

Comment: @BCLC i'll let you know the second i got something.

Comment: Wait i think it's unique simply because... if you have another measure $\lambda$ that satisfies the same property then $\mu$ and $\lambda$ will agree on $\pi (\mathbb R)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a related thing: [Show that $\mu((-\infty,x])$ is a unique measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446717/show-that-mu-infty-x-is-a-unique-measure)

---

## Part1 (intuition) - From $\mu$'s value at inputs of $[x,\infty)$, we can get $\mu$'s values at other inputs...hopefully every Borel set:

$[x,\infty)$ is a closed interval from $x$ until $\infty$. You know Gasai the output value assuming you input a closed interval $[x,\infty)$ into $\mu$. What if you input something that doesn't look like $[x,\infty)$? Use the properties of measure!

1. If I input $[3,4)$, then I can express $[3,4)$ as $[3,4) = [3,\infty) \ \setminus [4,\infty)$. Then $\mu([3,4)) = \mu([3,\infty) \ \setminus [4,\infty)) = \mu([3,\infty)) - \mu([4,\infty)$, by additivity (regular additivity not countable additivity!) of measure.
2. If I input $[3,4]$, then I can express $[3,4]$ as $[3,4] = \{4\} \cup [3,4) = \{4\} \cup ( [3,\infty) \ \setminus [4,\infty))$. Then $\mu([3,4]) = \mu([3,4)) + \mu(\{4\})$.

As for $\mu(\{4\})$ ugh... Hmmm...ahh use of continuity of measure. We have

$$\mu([4,4+\frac1n)) = \frac{\frac1n}{4(4+\frac1n)}$$

and

$$\{4\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [4,4+\frac1n)$$

and

$$[4,4+\frac1n) \supseteq [4,4+\frac1{n+1})$$

so continuity of measure gives us

$$\mu(\{4\}) = \lim \frac{\frac1n}{4(4+\frac1n)} = \frac0{16} = 0$$

Sooo we can similarly get $\mu$'s values from $(x,\infty)$, $(-\infty,x)$, $(-\infty,x]$, $(a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ soooo I guess we can get $\mu$'s value at any Borel set.

## Part2 - Proving it's a probability measure given it's a measure:

Easy. More than 1 way to do this I believe. 1 way I think is continuity of measure

$$\mu(\mathbb R) = \mu(-\infty,\infty) $$

$$= \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,\infty))$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu( [-n,\infty))$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} 1$$

$$= 1$$

## Part3 - Proving it's unique given it's a probability measure:

Hmmm...I know there's a uniqueness lemma that says if measures agree on a $\pi$-system $\mathscr A$, then they agree on the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathscr A)$.

From David Williams' Probability with Martingales:

> [image]

I think what you have to show here is if you have some other probability measure $\nu$ with the same formula as $\mu$ on $[x,\infty)$ then it'll have the same formula as $\mu$ on all Borel sets... **ugh...not so sure...** I think once you've shown it is a probability measure then it is a unique probability measure at least the way I did above because you can get the value of $\mu$ at any Borel set hmmmmm...

Well... $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) = \sigma(\mathscr A)$ with $\mathscr A = \pi(\mathscr R) := \{(-\infty,a]\}_{a \in \mathbb R}$, so just get the formula for $\mu$ on $\pi(\mathscr R)$, i.e. find the value of $\mu((-\infty,x])$ for every $x$ and then...yeah by the uniqueness lemma this $\mu$ is unique.

- For $x \le 0$, $\mu((-\infty,x]) = 0$
- For $x > 0$,

$$\mu((-\infty,x]) = \mu((0,x]) = \mu([0,x)) = \mu([0,\infty)) - \mu([x,\infty)) = 1 - \frac1{1+x} = \frac{x}{1+x}$$

**Edit**:

Wait i think it's unique simply because... if you have another measure $\lambda$ that satisfies the same property then $\mu$ and $\lambda$ will agree on $\pi (\mathbb R)$ ? Idk. I think it should be obvious, but I'm not really sure how to say this.